# undefined index error in jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Please check my code in the following:

PHP & HTML Code(file1.php):

```
<?php
$conn = //connected to db successfully.
$sql = "SELECT t1.column1 AS Column_1 FROM table1 t1";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
do{
?>
<button data-id="<?php echo $rows['Column_1']; ?>" type="button" onclick="handle_item('id')">Click Me</button> <br>
<?php }while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)); ?>
```

jQuery AJAX code(file1.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var item_id;
    function handle_item(item_id) {
        var c = $(this).data(item_id);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'handle_input.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'button_id': c
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

PHP Code(handle_input.php):

```
<?php
echo "Button with id ".$_POST['item_id]." clicked!";
?>
```

Now the problems is (as you might expect) the infamous error in this case, "undefined index: button_id" error. I receive it as an alert error when I click on one of the buttons. I've already read the duplicate questions on SO but unfortunately none of those I read could resolve my problem. I appreciate your guiding me with this.

Besides, as you see from my codes, I'm fetching several button from database and while displaying, I assign each one a data-id and use that data-id in ajax to use in 'handle_input.php' and I want to receive each button id which I've clicked on. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

It's been a while since I've asked this question but I've been curios about something in my question:
Why doesn't the array mode(data: {"button_id":c}) work for me in the $.ajax function(which leads to undefined index error for the $_POST variable) whereas the string mode(data: "usg_id="+c) does?

Comment: Please give more details about the error you got, I mean the line and file you are getting error. Also you are using 'item_id' handle_input.php but in Ajax you are passing button_id, please check.

Comment: start by basic debugging in browser console and by inspecting request, `this` isn't what you think it is

Comment: @charlietfl changing the data mode from array mode to "button_id=+c" resolved my undefined index error. Also, As I've written in my last paragraph, I want to get each button id I click on? Is there any mistake with my `this` in function? Because no matter which button I click on, I only get the alert of button id 0. Could you suggest a fix for it?

Comment: suggest using a jQuery click handler instead of `onclick` or pass `this` as argument of `onclick`

Comment: @charlietfl Could you provide your last comment suggestion as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending:

```
button_id:..
```

but you're using, also with a missing `'`

```
$_POST['item_id]
```

change to:

```
$_POST["button_id"]
```

**UPDATE**

Add `this` as first parameter:

```
onclick="handle_item(this, 'id')"
```

Then, change`handle_item` function as this:

```
function handle_item(obj,item_id) {
    var c = $(obj).data(item_id);
```

Comment: That's my typing error in question, not the error cause in my original file. Besides, item_id is my function variable but as you can see I've used handle_input('id') for onclick event. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: At first i thought you had a problem trying to pass the element's id, but since you're just querying the dataset named `id` of `<button>` then its ok. You're retrieving correctly the `data-id`

Comment: Thanks for your answer vlzvl, Your **Update** just resolved my problem.

Comment: Please check my question update above. I appreciate if you could answer it as an update in your answer?Thanks in advance.

Comment: No problem, but couldn't understand the question :)

Comment: Please check the update again. I just changed it now.

Comment: Check [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) about the `$.ajax` documentation. Problem with `data:"usg_id="+c` approach is that values are not properly encoded before send and it's really usable only for `GET` (since its appended to end of url). What problem do you have with `data:{key:val}` approach?

Comment: I receive undefined index error for the post variable in php file which url is in $.ajax url (as an alert) when I use array mode.

Comment: What key you get `undefined`? the `button_id` ? In any case just `print_r` to check the structure of the incoming array so to get the desired key.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var item_id;
    function handle_item(item_id) {
        var c = $(this).data(item_id);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'handle_input.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data:"item_id="+c,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

There is no button_id defined in you function hence the error.
Also in handle_input you are fetching item_id

Comment: $_POST fetches the variable with the name you are passing the data. eg  key=value then you must use $_POST['key'] to get the value. It has nothing to do with function variable name

Comment: `item_id` is my function variable and as you can see I've used `handle_input('id)` for onclick event so the `c` variable would be `$(this).data('id')` which I think is correct. Isn't it? if it isn't, I appreciate your suggesting a fix for it.

Comment: But the value of `$_POST['key']' would be my 'c' variable: which will be the data-id value of my clicked button. Am I right?

Comment: it is correct. my comment the way in which you are passing the data from javascript to php

Comment: Please check my question update above. I appreciate if you could answer it as an update in your answer?Thanks in advance.